# pandas: how to aggregate a subset of groupby rows into a single row?

Tags: python, pandas

Here's what I'd like to do given the following input:

```
pd.DataFrame({'cat':['A','B','C','B','C','D','C','E'], 'value':[3,6,7,7,9,8,3,1]})

cat    value
A          3
B          6
C          7
B          7
C          9
D          8
C          3
E          1
```

1. Group by `cat` and sort descending:

   ```
   df.groupby('cat').sum().sort_values('value', ascending=False)

   cat    sum
   C       19
   B       13
   D        8
   A        3
   E        1
   ```
2. Leave rows that cumulatively add up to less than 90% as is, but the remaining rows combine into a single new category 'Other':

   ```
   cat    sum
   C       19
   B       13
   Other   12
   ```

How do I do the last step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let

```
result = df.groupby('cat').sum().sort_values('value', ascending=False)
```

Divide `result` by the total sum to obtain percentages:

```
In [139]: result.div(result.sum())
Out[139]: 
        value
cat          
C    0.431818
B    0.295455
D    0.181818
A    0.068182
E    0.022727
```

Take the cumulative sum:

```
In [140]: result.div(result.sum()).cumsum()
Out[140]: 
        value
cat          
C    0.431818
B    0.727273
D    0.909091
A    0.977273
E    1.000000
```

and build a boolean mask which is True where the cumsum is < 0.9:

```
In [141]: result.div(result.sum()).cumsum() < 0.9
Out[141]: 
     value
cat       
C     True
B     True
D    False
A    False
E    False
```

Select and sum the non-masked rows:

```
row = result.loc[~mask].sum()
row.name = 'Other'
```

Use `result.loc[mask]` to select the True rows, and append the "Other" row:

```
result = result.loc[mask]
result = result.append(row)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat':['A','B','C','B','C','D','C','E'], 'value':[3,6,7,7,9,8,3,1]})
result = df.groupby('cat').sum().sort_values('value', ascending=False)
mask = (result['value'].div(result['value'].sum()).cumsum() < 0.9)
result = result.loc[mask].append(pd.Series(result.loc[~mask].sum(), name='Other'))
print(result)
```

yields

```
       value
cat         
C         19
B         13
Other     12
```

Comment: Nice!  I think it's possible to streamline this with `result.loc[mask].append(np.Series(result.loc[~mask].sum(), name="Other")`

Comment: Yes, that would be more succinct :)